# Problem after install nvidia-340 or nvidia-352 on gt630

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 15.10

i have a GT 630 and I'm having trouble when I upgrade the NVIDIA driver to 340 or 352. Only drive working is nvidia-304

**NVIDIA-340**

After update to nvidia-340 i get a black screen, here is kernel.log

> [kernel.log - nvidia-340](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14688054/)

**NVIDIA-352**

And after update to nvidia-352, i can boot, but in low resolution and the driver seems to be not active, and "lsmod | grep nvidia" return nothing. Here is kernel.log

> [kernel.log - nvidia-352](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14688073/)

any help? I want to play dota 2, but the last driver support is 340

**My system config:**

System: Xubuntu 15.10 x64

Motherboard: g31m-vs2

Processor: Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E5700  @ 3.00GHz

Ram: 3GB

VGA: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 630] (rev a2)

Comment: "the driver seems to be not active". Could you please boot with nvidia-352 and give us the output of `lsmod | grep nvidia`?

Comment: @EduardoCola [lsmod | grep nvidia](http://i.imgur.com/k5raaG9.png) return nothing

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the currently installed NVIDIA drivers.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
Enter user name and password and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Install the NVIDIA drivers in an alternative way.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
Enter user name and password and execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo reboot
```

In case the drivers don't work ... try the latest official drivers from the NVIDIA short-lived branch.

Uninstall the currently installed NVIDIA drivers.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
Enter user name and password and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Install NVIDIA drivers from the GPU drivers PPA .

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
Enter user name and password and execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358
sudo reboot
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the problem continued.

Comment: @jeanroyce : Please check whether you have to activate the video card in BIOS. :)

Comment: yes is active, I can play cs:go with nvidia-304 drivers

Comment: sorry for delay, i tried but i get a blackscreen, and before starting appeared several crazy messages, no success. I removed ppa and back to nvidia-304

Comment: my ubuntu is Xubuntu 15.10, clean installation. I also tried with elementary x86 and still the same problem.

[some information of my system](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14690020/)

Comment: @jeanroyce : Maybe your NVIDIA GEFORCE GT 630 is not working properly anymore ... the drivers support this graphics chip and should work : drivers 352 -> http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/97645/en-us | drivers 358 -> http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/95921/en-us ! Sorry - I am running out of ideas ... :)

Comment: Actually you had a point. Went on to disassemble the GPU and found out that the whole card was a fake one. Should have bought a better one...